# saving dynamically created data + c# + powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have an application that runs a powershell script and I need to save the data that the powershell script returns.

An example of a script that might be passed to the application is:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object -Property name, status
```

Here is my C# code for running the script and saving the results:

```
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
powershell.Runspace.Open();
powershell.AddScript(scriptText);
var results = powershell.Invoke();
```

I then filter the members of the returned collection to find those I'm really looking for

```
var firstobject = results[0].Members;   
foreach(PSMemberInfo memberInfo in firstobject)
{          
    if (!listOfStrings.Contains(memberInfo.Name))
    {
        //Do something with this -- stuck
    }
}
```

The goal is to not hard code anything, so I need to dynamically create a table or something, that can hold my return memberinfo (which can be any number of properties)
and I then need that to get the return values of said memberinfo properties AND THEN save it to an SQL table in a proper format.

Am I missing something in the powershell output or is there a framework to format the output so it's easier to use?

How do I save data I do not know anything about, other than the amount of items and the name of the properties?

I'm thinking of saving the data to a SQL table and from there loading it into a view of some kind.

I'm trying to find a solution that will work for any number of properties 
any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PSMemberInfo has properties such as Name, Value for which you can create a table to store them. So you can store any number of properties as name value pairs.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but i dont know which properties Are to be used. The thing is - the user will be making scripts -  they will all have "select-object -property" at the end, but i need to create it so the user chooses the properties and the application the sorts the output into tables from whatever memberinfo it can find. I just dont know how

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through the powershell output? That isnt a foreach item in psobject... .value - and how do i link it it to the memberinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Dictionary object like this or create a custom class and store each PSMemberInfo object into a list. So your Table could be of just Name,Value stuff and other metadata. Try commenting our the other scriptText and it has different property and still the dictionary object gets all the properties.  For demo purposes I am using only one object from the result set.
Update: there is no first in the script but just to get the type of the object being returned I am doing `powershell.Invoke().First().Members`.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var scriptText = "Get-Process | Select *";
        //var scriptText = "Get-Service";
        var scriptText = "Get-Service | Select ServiceName, Status";
        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        powershell.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        powershell.Runspace.Open();
        powershell.AddScript(scriptText);

        Dictionary<string, object> dictprop = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (PSMemberInfo item in powershell.Invoke().First().Members)
        {
            try
            {
                dictprop.Add(item.Name, item.Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Value = {1}", item.Name, item.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Null Value invocation exception.
            }

        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: very nice! but what do I do, when I'm not using -First? - without using a foreach in the script it self?

Comment: Ok so do you want to store properties of just the type of object being returned irrespective of the number of objects being returned?

Comment: check the updated answer without the first in the scriptText.

Comment: You are still only taking the first item - I need all items with an undefined number of properties. with your example - how do i get all items?

Comment: All the results returned by the powershell pipeline will of a particular type and I enumerate properties of just one. Why get properties of all objects when they are going to be the same.  Or may be I didn't get your questions altogether.

Comment: I can't hardcode the properties, the user will be making the powershell script from a standard with select-object -properties prop1, prop2, prop3 (of the users choosing). I need to present this in a table. i need to return the full list of items in let's say "get-netadapter" with 3 properties i cant hardcode.

Comment: There is no hardcoded properties and I am able to get any number properties supplied in select using the code above.

Comment: yes your code works, its seems i didnt understand your answer, i already had working code for getting the properties (yours is better though). my question is how do i get all items with their properties and save them in a table of some sort?